Can someone explain the working principle of this diagram?

In my opinion, during daytime because our battery is only 3V, the solar panel produces more voltage and because of voltage difference, voltage flows from solar panel to battery and there is no sufficient voltage from panel to base through resistor to turn transistor ON. In night time, the battery has more voltage and the solar panel will act as a less resistive short circuit path and voltage flows from the battery through the solar panel through the resistor to the base of the transistor to turn it on and the LED glows. What do you think?

Pradeep Kandel - Hi, As you're asking how it works, this can't be your design. So where did it come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. || If the source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage / PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full details of the source e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

Always consider redrawing the schematic. What you have is exactly the same as this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Assume the solar cell, when lit sufficiently, produces more than \$4.5\:\text{V}\$, just to pick a number more than \$3\:\text{V}\$. then the clamp diode will maintain \$V_1\approx -600\:\text{mV}\$, strongly. That will certainly keep the NPN off. So no current for the LED.
When the solar cell isn't lit, then it is, itself, more like a weak resistor that leaks a small current from the \$+3\:\text{V}\$ supply and through R to turn the NPN on.
Some details probably matter. The solar cell does need to produce at least \$3\:\text{V}\$ at the light level required to turn the LED off. It does not need to generate much current, when lit. So a really small one is sufficient, not needing a lot of area.
And the solar cell does need to leak a little, when unlit.
The LED should allow the the NPN to remain in active mode (higher \$\beta\$.) So probably anything under \$2.4\:\text{V}\$ when operating, with still lower voltage requirements being better.
The rest is a matter of tuning the circuit. If a high efficiency RED LED is used, then the leakage only needs to be a few microamps (the NPN will be in active mode and at full \$\beta\$) and this may increase the range of solar cells that can be usefully used. Other LEDs may require leakage of tens of microamps. But it's not much leakage, regardless.
Adding a high valued potentiometer across the solar cell may be worth considering. Or using one temporarily while "calibrating" the desired light level and then replacing with a simple resistor.

+1 for redrawing the schematics. a good way to go from "Wait! What???" and spending 20 seconds to figure out what's this mess, to "Obvious" at the blink of an eye....

yes. that's how I think it works too.
photovoltaic cells are known to leak current when it's dark. so leakage current through the solar cell turns the NPN transistor on at night.
